# Mounting a different SSHFS automatically depending on location

Tags: linux, ssh, sshfs

Basically, we have a local server and a remote server.  The remote server is for out-of-the-office.

It's easy to easily have it mount a folder over SSH to the remote server.

However, when in the office, I would like it to mount using the local server, since the latency is much less.

I know this can be done manually by using two different commands to mount depending on where I am, but I was wondering if this could be automated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to refer to the server using DNS and then have split DNS so that local DNS requests resolve to the internal servers IO and remote requests get a different IP.

There are a few ways of doing this, including using dnsmasq locally with a hosts file or configuring bind to answer differently depending on interface/IP range.

Comment: DNS did come to mind, but I wasn't sure how to solve the DNS problem locally. I didn't know about dnsmasq, thanks!